# SQL query to insert FIRST row on a table

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table with 10 columns, and two of the columns are project and employee.

- What I am attempting to do is I have a drop down list of values for
  the employee field in this table,
- And I need to do an INSERT statement into the same table, inserting
  all of the values that exist in the table, and just change the value
  of the employee field on inserting.
- I only want to insert a single record, so I am fearing that if I
  execute an insert statement  with on a WHERE project equals what the
  user selected, that I will get thousands of rows inserted.
- I just want to insert one single row from the table where the project
  field is equal to what the user selected in a drop down, and insert
  one single row copying all the data of a single row of that project,
  and
- Just replace the employee field with what the user selected in a
  drop down.

Comment: What scripting language you are using, `Php`, `ASP` etc?

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server (MSSQL) is not the same software. Which one do you use? Please change the tags to the relevant DBMS.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to do an UPDATE? INSERT means to add a new row. UPDATE means to change an existing row.

Comment: Yes.  I need to INSERT a new row into the same table, selecting only one row that is already in the table for the selected project field, and inserting all of those values with the new value of the employee field that the user selects

Comment: I am using an ASPX page with C# code behind.

Comment: So WHICH row do you want? You have to decide which row you are getting the new values from.

Answer (score 1):

You can `INSERT` using `SELECT TOP 1` to get a row from the existing table with a `WHERE` clause that includes the required `Project`, like so:

```
DECLARE @EmployeeIdToAdd int = 12345
DECLARE @ProjectId int = 10

INSERT INTO [ProjectEmployees] (Col1, Col2,..., Project, Employee)
SELECT TOP 1 Col1, Col2,..., Project, @EmployeeIdToAdd
FROM ProjectEmployees
WHERE Project = @ProjectId
```

You would just need to set the parameters accordingly.